# BizTalk 2013 R2 CU 8 instalaltion

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

While installing the Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 R2 Cumulative update 8 to one BizTalk group, the setup fails because of some issue in MQSeries and Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas. No errors or issues could be spotted at the Event log. Even on another BizTalk server (with almost identical installation) was successful. Please refer to the log information below. Please share tips what to investigate.

```
Creating Process to execute script: "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c BtsDeploySystemAssemblyTask.exe /assembly:MQSeries /version:3.0.1.0  HRESULT=0 
Execution of Script "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c BtsDeploySystemAssemblyTask.exe /assembly:MQSeries /version:3.0.1.0 failed. HRESULT=0x80004005 
 ****************************** Processing MQSeries migration from Registry to Database ******************************
Server = SQL\BTS Database = BizTalkMgmtDb
Taking Backup of tables
Getting Id of MQSeries
SQL Exception occured. An error occured while adding MQSeries
Incorrect Assembly no. and/or Version no. mentioned. Exiting.
Incorrect Assembly no. and/or Version no. mentioned. Exiting.
 HRESULT=0 
Failed to apply patch. HRESULT=0x80004005 
Apply patch: Server="SQL\BTS", Database="BizTalkMgmtDb", Script="C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\E-Business Servers Updates\Updates\Uninstall4052527\CAWrapper.exe".
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\E-Business Servers Updates\Updates\Uninstall4052527\CAWrapper.exe" 2 3.11.297.2 SQL\BTS BizTalkMgmtDb EXE "BtsDeploySystemAssemblyTask.exe /assembly:Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas" HRESULT=0 
Creating Process to execute script: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\E-Business Servers Updates\Updates\Uninstall4052527\CAWrapper.exe" 2 3.11.297.2 SQL\BTS BizTalkMgmtDb EXE "BtsDeploySystemAssemblyTask.exe /assembly:Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas"  HRESULT=0 
Execution of Script "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\E-Business Servers Updates\Updates\Uninstall4052527\CAWrapper.exe" 2 3.11.297.2 SQL\BTS BizTalkMgmtDb EXE "BtsDeploySystemAssemblyTask.exe /assembly:Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas" failed. HRESULT=0x80004005 
CAWrapper: Argument count:  6
CAWrapper: cuNum: 2, btsVer: 3.11.297.2, servername: SQL\BTS, databasename: BizTalkMgmtDb, command: EXE
CAWrapper: cmdArg#0: BtsDeploySystemAssemblyTask.exe /assembly:Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas
CAWrapper: Entering isDbVersionLower
CAWrapper: Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=BizTalkMgmtDb;Data Source=SQL\BTS
CAWrapper: No DB Version info found so assuming DB Version is lower.
CAWrapper: DB Version in SQL\BTS, BizTalkMgmtDb is lower so need to run command.
CAWrapper: Entering callEXE
CAWrapper: Calling BtsDeploySystemAssemblyTask.exe with args  /assembly:Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas
 ****************************** Processing Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas migration from Registry to Database ******************************
Server = SQL\BTS Database = BizTalkMgmtDb
Taking Backup of tables
Getting Id of Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas
SQL Exception occured. An error occured while adding Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas
Multiple entries of assembly available. Version is not mentioned
Multiple entries of assembly available. Version is not mentioned

CAWrapper: Call to BtsDeploySystemAssemblyTask.exe returned
CAWrapper: Failure calling BM.exe.  ExitCode was 1
CAWrapper: Exiting...
 HRESULT=0 
Failed to apply patch. HRESULT=0x80004005 
Abort distributed transaction.
Failed to patch one or more BizTalk databases. See log for details. (HRESULT=0x80004005)
The custom action returned -2147467259.
One of the custom actions failed. The installation cannot continue. See log for details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation with SQL Profiler on the BizTalk management database (BizTalkMgmtDb) I found some duplicate records present in bts_assembly. After removing the duplicate ones (wich do not have references to bts_item table) the CU was installed without any issue.